# Will video buffering have any impact to video over a slow connection?

Tags: actionscript-3

This more of a sanity check question, I'm beginning to doubt myself.

As I understand it video over a connection of say 40Kb/s wont actually have time to load and make a buffer, and it'll be "glitchy", so it wont make much difference whatever buffering is put in place.

I'm getting complaints about glitchy video. I don't have access to the servers serving the media so I put a load timer in a swf along the lines of

```
averageLoadSpeed = (bytesLoaded / loadTimer.currentCount) / 1024;
```

Out of 5 tests run, 2 were below 50Kb/s. And I've been told the server also is not geared towards media and put priorities on other business tasks. The head of IT for this company keeps going at me about buffering, and how that'll fix the problem. I tried to explain that the speed is way too low

(32Mb = 32768Kb / 24Kb/s = 1,365 seconds * 60 = 22min)

Can anyone enlighten me on buffering aside from wikipedia's explanation about IO streams. I don't know how to put it simply, I think of buffering as just a user experience addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Flash or Acrionscript but from a general point of view.

Buffering is generally there to absorb a random slowdown or network congestion, if the max speed of the media being served is lower than the bit rate of the video, buffering will allow it to play a bit, stop and buffer, play a bit more.

What bit rate is the video encoded at?

A 1MB buffer for a CBR video (no audio) at a bit rate of 128Kbs will take approx 2mins to buffer @ 56Kbs for 1 min of video. While that 1 min of video plays you will have downloaded another 30 seconds of video, then another 15, 7, 3, 1 done.

Another example however,
1MB buffer for a CBR video (no audio) at a bit rate of 1Mbs will take approx 2mins to buffer @ 56Kbs for 7 seconds of video, in which time you might not have downloaded another seconds worth of video.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't know that much about buffering and bitrates. I just used mediainfo to have a look. It says the video is 375 Kbps, and the audio is.... 320 Kbps and 2 channels of sound. I'm not sure who encoded the video but I'm thinking that ain't the best.

Comment: Not if it's a music video and the music is the most important bit, but yes an audio bitrate that is nearly the same as the video bitrate is a bit odd.